# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of custom piecewise distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, piecewise-pdf

Recently I've been working with the distribution described by the pdf below:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3(b-a)}(1+\frac{x-a}{x-c}) & \quad a<x<c \\
\frac{2}{3(b-a)}(1+\frac{b-x}{b-c}) & \quad c<x<b,
\end{cases} 
 $$
$$a<c<b, a>0.$$

Essentially, this describes what I call a "raised triangular" distribution, meaning a distribution where there is a clear peak, but values towards the edges are still fairly common. There is also a well-defined minimum and maximum. $a$ represents the minimum, $b$ represents the maximum, and $c$ represents the mode.

I've been wanting to derive estimators for the parameters of the distribution. It's tempting to just say that, given an ordered data set $X = \{x_{(1)}, x_{(2)},\ldots,x_{(n)}\}$, $a = x_{(1)}$, $b = x_{(n)}$, and $c$ equals some estimation of the mode. However, I'd like to find a more mathematically rigorous approach to this.

I've been working on deriving the likelihood function for this distribution, but the piecewise nature of it complicates things. I eventually settled on:

$$L(\hat{a}, \hat{b}, \hat{c} /X) = \left(\frac{2}{3(b-a)}\right)^n \prod_{i=1}
^{\left\lfloor\frac{\hat{c}-\hat{a}}{\hat{b}-\hat{a}}n\right\rfloor}\left(1+\frac{x_{(i)} - \hat{a}}{x_{(i)} - \hat{c}}\right) \prod_{i = \left\lceil\frac{\hat{c}-\hat{a}}{\hat{b}-\hat{a}}n\right\rceil}^{n}\left(1+\frac{\hat{b}-x_{(i)}}{\hat{b}-\hat{c}}\right)$$

The log-likelihood can then be derived from this, though this function is not differentiable, so I gave up on finding an analytical solution and am working on maximization algorithms now. However, I'm unsure if this formulation of the likelihood function is correct. Specifically, I'm sceptical of the bounds of the products. My logic is that a certain percentage of points will fall below $c$, which I estimate as the distance between $a$ and $c$ over the distance between $c$ and $b$, multiply this by the number of observations (and take the floor to round to an integer). This way, the estimation of the number of observations below $c$ is based on the parameters themselves.

In my first initial tests with this function, however, the results aren't making sense. Does anyone have any pointers on where to go from here? Or should I abandon this approach and go with the more "naive" one based on mins and maxes?

Comment: You have a typo: $1+\frac{x−a}{x−c}$ should be $1+\frac{x−a}{c−a}$.  And same typo/error in the likelihood:  $x_{(i)}-\hat{c}$ should be $\hat{c}-\hat{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment to emphasize that the pdf presented is wrong.  If a "raised triangular" distribution is what is desired, then the probability density function is given by

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 \frac{2}{3(b-a)}(1+\frac{x-a}{c-a}) & \quad a<x\leq c \\
 \frac{2}{3(b-a)}(1+\frac{b-x}{b-c}) & \quad c<x<b 
\end{cases} 
$$
$$a<c<b$$

An example plot of the pdf using R follows:

```
f <- function(x, a, b, c) {

  if (a > x | b < x | c < a | c > b | a > b) {
     0
  } else {
     if (x <= c) {
        2*(1 + (x-a)/(c-a))/(3*(b-a))
     } else {
        2*(1 + (b-x)/(b-c))/(3*(b-a))
     } 
  }
}

x <- c(-100:1100)/1000
y <- lapply(x, f, a=0, b=1, c=0.3)
plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=3, xlab="x", ylab="Probability density", cex.lab=1.5,
  font.lab=2, las=1, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, pos=0)
axis(2, las=1, pos=-0.1)
lines(c(-0.1, -0.1, 1.1, 1.1, -0.1), c(0, 1.35, 1.35, 0, 0))
```

[image: pdf example]